# QGIS Batch process of Clipping Raster by Extents using For loop from Python Console

Tags: qgis, clip, extents, batch, qgis-python-console

I am clipping a raster by extents from the python console in QGIS by using the following code :

```
from processing.tools import *  
general.runalg("gdalogr:cliprasterbyextent","E:/Sreeraj/Task/Split/Extract_agri.tif","","-180.0,0.0,0.0,90.0",5,4,75,6,1,False,0,False,"","E:/Sreeraj/Task/Split/output/1.tif")
```

Here, I am giving extents as minimum_longitude=180.0, minimum_latitude=0.0, maximim_longitude=0.0, and maximum_latitude=90.0.

Now, I want to do a clipping using processing.runalg in QGIS python console, where I will use a for loop for clipping 4 output .tif files as a batch process.

For doing this batch process of clipping, I tried the given below code:

```
output_location = "E:/Sreeraj/Task/Split/output/"
output file = 1
for long in range(-180,0,5):
  longmax = long + 5
  for lat in range(0,90,5):
    latmax = lat + 5
    extents = "long,lat,longmax,latmax" 
    output = str(output_location) + str(output file) + ".tif" 
    general.runalg("gdalogr:cliprasterbyextent","E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/Extract_agri.TIF","",extents,5,4,75,6,1,False,0,False,"",output)
    output file = output file + 1
```

Unfortunately, I am getting error message as :

```
"Error: Wrong parameter value: extents"
```

Instead of directly giving the extent values like "-180.0,0.0,0.0,90.0" inside general.runalg(), how can I give  "extents" (if extents = "-180,0,0,90").

I think that the issue is with :

```
extents = "long,lat,longmax,latmax"
```

When I do like this :

```
extents = "-180.0,0.0,0.0,90.0"
general.runalg("gdalogr:cliprasterbyextent","E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/Extract_agri.TIF","",extents,5,4,75,6,1,False,0,False,"",output)
```

then the code is working.

But, if I do like this :

```
long = -180.0 
lat = 0.0
longmax = 0.0 
latmax = 90.0  
extents = "long,lat,longmax,latmax"
general.runalg("gdalogr:cliprasterbyextent","E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/Extract_agri.TIF","",extents,5,4,75,6,1,False,0,False,"",output)
```

then I am getting the error.

So, clearly, the issue is with :

```
extents = "longmin,longmax,latmin,latmax"
```

Please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put your variables inside single quotation marks which means whatever is inside those quotes will be read as it is written. So if you type `extents`, it would show up as:

```
'long,lat,longmax,latmax'
```

Remove the quotes and you should get something like:

```
(-180.0, 0.0, 0.0, 90.0)
```

This would be closer to what you are looking for but I'm not sure if tuples are accepted as a parameter for the extent (tuples are a sequence of objects inside brackets).

---

Also, the extent parameters are given by (or at least the last time I checked):

```
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax
```

So in your case it would be:

```
long, longmax, lat, latmax
```

And if you want to see this as an extent parameter, you could use:

```
extents = "%f,%f,%f,%f"% (long, longmax, lat, latmax)
```

---

So your final code could look like (*note that I change `long` to `lon` as the former is used by Python; and `output file` to `output_file`*):

```
output_location = "E:/Sreeraj/Task/Split/output/"
output_file = 1
for lon in range(-180,0,5):
    longmax = lon + 5
    for lat in range(0,90,5):
        latmax = lat + 5
        extents = "%f,%f,%f,%f"% (lon, longmax, lat, latmax)
        output = str(output_location) + str(output_file) + ".tif" 
        general.runalg("gdalogr:cliprasterbyextent","E:/Sreeraj/Task Global Data CONVERSION/Split/Extract_agri.TIF","",extents,5,4,75,6,1,False,0,False,"",output)
        output_file = output_file + 1
```

Comment: Perfectly working solution to this issue.                                                
                                                                                                              
    extents = "%f,%f,%f,%f"% (lon, longmax, lat, latmax)                                                                           
                                                                                                           Thank You.

Comment: @Sreeraj - Most welcome, glad it helped :)